# Why there's no isClosed function at Network.Socket

Tags: sockets, haskell, networking

In the [`Network.Socket`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.6.3.2/docs/Network-Socket.html) module there are functions like [`isConnected`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.6.3.2/docs/Network-Socket.html#t:SocketStatus), [`isBound`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.6.3.2/docs/Network-Socket.html#t:SocketStatus), etc. but there is no `isClosed` function, to check whether a socket is closed.

I'm writing a module that needs to close a socket connection:

```
import qualified Network.Socket as Socket

-- ...

close Connection{connSock, serverSock} = do
    Socket.close connSock
    Socket.close serverSock
```

The problem is that this if the socket is already closed (for instance on the client side), I'll get the following error:

```
epollControl: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

So I now I'm checking that the socket is open before closing it:

```
  closeIfOpen sock = do
      let MkSocket _ _ _ _ stMV = sock
      st <- readMVar stMV
      case st of
          Closed -> return ()
          _ -> Socket.close sock
```

While this works, the lack of an `isClosed` function makes me wonder whether the code above has some potential problem that I'm not aware of (for instance it has a race condition, but my guess is that `isConnected` and `isBound` should have it as well...).

Comment: I guess the maintainer https://github.com/haskell/network could answer the question.

Comment: The functionality you are asking for is still buggy since you can race, getting a client closing the connection between checking if it's closed and the call to close.  I'm surprised this causes an exception in the first place, but why don't you just catch and ignore the exception?  If the exception is non-unique then file an issue.